# Transferring a text file's contents over socket.io results in a ArrayBuffer object

Tags: json, node.js, socket.io

I am a newbie with `socket.io` and have very little exposure to `node.js` as well

So I started from the simple chat app and built my way up

I can get text messages to be sent from a server to a client when the message comes from another client, like the chat demo app does

But when trying to have the server read a local file and send this contents over using `io.emit`, what the client side receives seems to be an instance of `ArrayBuffer`, which in any case confuses the JSON parser

More specifically, server side does

```
fs.watch('status.json', 
  function(event, filename){
    fs.readFile('status.json',
      function(err, data){
        if (err) throw err;
      io.emit("r2lab status", data);
      });
  });
```

and client side does

```
socket.on('r2lab status', function(json){
    console.log("received JSON nodes_info " + json);
    var nodes_info = JSON.parse(json);
    /* etc.. */
```

which at run-time triggers this in Console

```
received JSON nodes_info [object ArrayBuffer]
r2lab.html:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o
...
```

As the logic works when I am getting my input by another source than a file, this  all strongly suggests that the `data` I am getting out of `readFile` is not a plain string but some kind of instance that somehow makes it to the client side; like if I had opened my input file in binary or something.

Could anyone suggest a means to get JSON.parse() to be happy with this scenario ? server-side or client-side, either way would be just fine with me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Uint8Array` view to access that `ArrayBuffer` and then convert it to string:

```
socket.on('r2lab status', function(data){
  var buffer = new Uint8Array(data)
  var fileString= String.fromCharCode.apply(null, buffer)
  var obj = JSON.parse(fileString)
});
```

Comment: OK, thanks, this is quite helpful and does the job for me